# Curl in Php - Google Analytics Api

Tags: php, curl

i downloaded and extracted Google Api for php and try to retrieve data from Google Analytics.

when i install google api , i recognize that i have to install the extension 'CURL'.

i made a research about it and i activate it from php.ini and install needed dll's

despite all of this i doesnt works.

i take the error below
[image]

actually there is a file named 'apiClient.php' and in apiClient.php  there are a few lines that  check CURL is activated or not.

```
if (! function_exists('curl_init')) {
  throw new Exception('Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension');
}
```

is there anything that i miss ? What is the problem ? How can i activate CURL?

Answer (score 2):

Restarting apache is the solution :)